# ELKI CSV parser problems

Tags: parsing, data-mining, elki

I have changed an .arff file to a .csv file in a tool in Weka. 
But now I can't use the arffparser as parser in ELKI.

What parser should I then use? The default is NumberVectorLabelParser. But it gives me a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

```
Running: -verbose -verbose -dbc.in /home/db/lisbet/Datasets/without ids/try 2/calling them .txt using another parser/Lymphography_withoutdupl_norm_1ofn.csv -dbc.parser NumberVectorLabelParser -algorithm outlier.lof.LOF -lof.k 2 -evaluator outlier.OutlierROCCurve -rocauc.positive yes
Task failed
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 47
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser.getTypeInformation(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:337)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser.buildMeta(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:242)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.NumberVectorLabelParser.nextEvent(NumberVectorLabelParser.java:211)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.bundle.MultipleObjectsBundle.fromStream(MultipleObjectsBundle.java:242)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.parser.AbstractStreamingParser.asMultipleObjectsBundle(AbstractStreamingParser.java:89)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.datasource.InputStreamDatabaseConnection.loadData(InputStreamDatabaseConnection.java:91)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.database.StaticArrayDatabase.initialize(StaticArrayDatabase.java:119)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.workflow.InputStep.getDatabase(InputStep.java:62)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.KDDTask.run(KDDTask.java:108)
    at de.lmu.ifi.dbs.elki.application.KDDCLIApplication.run(KDDCLIApplication.java:60)
    at [...]
```

My .csv file looks like this:

```
'Lymphatics = deformed','Lymphatics = displaced','Lymphatics = arched','Lymphatics = normal','Block_of_affere = yes','Block_of_affere = no','Bl_of_lymph_c = no','Bl_of_lymph_c = yes','Bl_of_lymph_s = no','Bl_of_lymph_s = yes','By_pass = no','By_pass = yes','Extravasates = yes','Extravasates = no','Regeneration_of = no','Regeneration_of = yes','Early_uptake_in = yes','Early_uptake_in = no','Changes_in_lym = oval','Changes_in_lym = round','Changes_in_lym = bean','Defect_in_node = lacunar','Defect_in_node = lac_central','Defect_in_node = lac_margin','Defect_in_node = no','Changes_in_node = lac_central','Changes_in_node = lacunar','Changes_in_node = no','Changes_in_node = lac_margin','Changes_in_stru = faint','Changes_in_stru = drop_like','Changes_in_stru = stripped','Changes_in_stru = coarse','Changes_in_stru = diluted','Changes_in_stru = grainy','Changes_in_stru = no','Changes_in_stru = reticular','Special_forms = vesicles','Special_forms = no','Special_forms = chalices','Dislocation_of = no','Dislocation_of = yes','Exclusion_of_no = yes','Exclusion_of_no = no',Lym_nodes_dimin,Lym_nodes_enlar,No_of_nodes_in,Outlier
1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0.333333,0.285714,no
0,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0.333333,0.142857,no
```

There are 11 parsers available. But maybe it is my data, that is to large for the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, this is a bug in the ELKI CSV parser.

It did not expect the class column to have a label.

So if your remove the `,Outlier` part of your first line (or the first line completely), it should read this file just fine.

I will push a change that makes it more robust here (it will still lose the label though, because ELKI currently has support column labels for numerical columns but not for string label columns).

Comment: Thanks, now I get a result ROCAUC: 0.7436676798378926 but it is a different result than running the same file, when it was an .arff file (ROCAUC: 0.8274647887323944)
And I only changed the file via 'save-as .csv file' in Weka and deleted the word Outlier in gedit.

Comment: When I deleted ALL the (header)line in the .csv file I got ROCAUC: 0.8274647887323944, the same as I get for the arff file. YAY!

Comment: That should not make a difference.